# Is there a word for an intentional misnomer?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetorical-devices

Is there a word that describes that something has been named "incorrectly" on purpose (a sort of *intentional misnomer*)? For example, calling someone who is very tall Shorty (or something to that effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *malicious malapropism*?

[While a [malapropism](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malapropism) is usually unintentional, the adjective suggests the deliberate twist.]

Comment: Hmm- maybe, I don't want to suggest it's mean spirited...

Comment: @batpigandme Maybe *jocular malapropism*?

Comment: @batpigandme or to maintain the consonance, *mischievous malapropism*?

Comment: Jocular malapropism is perfect (though I definitely plan on making use of mischievous malapropism when I'm feeling alliterative...)

Answer (score 8):

If the intentional misnomer disparages something positive (as, arguably, calling a tall person Shorty does), it qualifies as a *dysphemism*. From *The Oxford Companion to the English Language* (1992):

> **DYSPHEMISM**  In rhetoric, the use of a negative or disparaging expression to describe something or someone, such as calling a Rolls-Royce a *jalopy*. A cruel or offensive dysphemism is a *cacophemism*.

Another candidate (though not quite so apt) from the same source is *meiosis*:

> **MEIOSIS** In rhetoric, a kind of understatement that dismisses or belittles, especially by using terms that make something seem less significant than it really is or ought to be: for example, calling a serious wound a *scratch*, or a journalist a *hack* or a *scribbler*.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking of a less disparaging tone, but cool word!

Comment: Plus one for "rhetoric"!

Comment: I would simply add, or add simply, whichever you prefer, that naming something wrongly and intentionally is a mild form of irony and is sometimes totally lacking in imagination.   Calling a tall person "Shorty," or a milquetoast "Tiger" is just too facile!

Answer (score 5):

Antiphrasis! Sometimes conflated with litotes.

> #### Antiphrasis
>
> the usually ironic or humorous use of words in senses opposite to the generally accepted meanings (as in "this giant of 3 feet 4 inches")
>
> [[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antiphrasis)]